# UART/DMA interrupt not being triggered on dsPIC33

Tags: c, interrupt, uart, microchip, dma

I have a dsPIC33 with an explorer board 16. The entire code base is fairly lengthy but the problem is isolated to the DMA interrupt. It is not being triggered even though I have pretty much copied the Microchip UARTloopback example. I have read the Microchip manual section for both the UART and DMA thoroughly and the loopback example does work, however when it is implemented with my code it does not. I have checked my entire project to make sure that the DMA channels are not being overwritten or used anywhere else in the project. The same applies to the UART section. I will be including the entire file c file and h file. Functions to focus on are the uart_commInit, BEACON_uart_commPuts, and _DMA3Interrupt. The BEACON_uart_commPuts works and prints to the terminal. Everything compiles

uart.c

```
    /**
 * This source file contains functions for using the UARTs. 
 *
 * @todo Write uart_monitor() or ISR to check for UART parity, framing error and DMA collisions
 *
 * @ingroup CSuart 
 * @defgroup CSuart UART
 * @{
 * High level functions for UART with DMA. Function names
 * beginning  with uart_comm... are for communicating with the transceiver. The
 * UART peripheral used for the transceiver can be changed by editing the macros
 * in CSuart.h.
 */

/* System & Local Includes */
#include <p33Fxxxx.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "CSdefine.h"
#include "types.h"
#include "CSuart.h"

/* Type and Constant Definitions*/
// Handshake control signals for Devboard USB
#define HS0         BIT4      // RC4
#define HS1         BIT3      // RC3
#define HS2         BIT2      // RC2
#define HS3         BIT5      // RD5
#define HS4         BIT2      // RD2
#define HS5         BIT1      // RD1

// Motherboard control signals
#define CS_SD_BAR   BIT5      // RE5
#define OE_USB_BAR  BIT1      // RC1
#define OE_MHX_BAR  BIT2      // RE2
#define ON_SD_BAR   BIT4      // RE4
#define ON_MHX_BAR  BIT3      // RE3

/* Global & Local Variables */
// DMA TX and RX buffers for comm UART
static uint16 txBuff[RADIO_TX_BUFFER_SIZE] __attribute__((space(dma)));
static uint16 rxBuff[RADIO_RX_BUFFER_SIZE] __attribute__((space(dma)));

static uint16 tx0Buff[BEACON_TX_BUFFER_SIZE] __attribute__((space(dma)));
static uint16 rx0Buff[BEACON_TX_BUFFER_SIZE] __attribute__((space(dma)));

static uint16 *lastRead = (uint16 *) &rxBuff; // Points to next transfer to be read from DMA rxBuff
static uint16 *lastRead0 = (uint16 *) &rx0Buff; // Points to next transfer to be read from DMA rxBuff

/* Functions */

/******************************************************************************
 ****                                                                       ****
 **                                                                           **
 csk_usb_open()  Enable USB on the Dev/Flight hardware

 **                                                                           **
 ****                                                                       ****
 ******************************************************************************/
void csk_usb_open(void) {

    // Disable all control signals to avoid spurious
    //  writes when -OE_USB goes active (LOW).
    PORTD |=  (HS5+HS4+HS3            );
    TRISD &= ~(HS5+HS4+HS3            );
//
//   // Configure -OE_USB as an output, and make
//    //  it active (i.e., LOW)
    PORTC &= ~OE_USB_BAR;
    TRISC &= ~OE_USB_BAR;

} /* csk_usb_open() */


/******************************************************************************
 ****                                                                       ****
 **                                                                           **
 csk_usb_close()  // Disable USB on the Dev/flight hardware

 **                                                                           **
 ****                                                                       ****
 ******************************************************************************/
void csk_usb_close(void) {

    // Restore -OE_USB to an input.
    PORTC |=  OE_USB_BAR;
    TRISC |=  OE_USB_BAR;

} /* csk_usb_close() */

/**
 * Initializes the UART port with DMA for use for satellite comm (ie. the transceiver). 
 * This should be called sometime during startup.
 */
void uart_commInit(){

// Configure UART for 9600 8N1 with interrupts to the DMA module
    RADIO_UMODEbits.UEN = 0b10;      //UxTX, UxRX, UxCTS and UxRTS pins are enabled and used
    RADIO_UMODEbits.PDSEL = 0b00;    //8-bit data, no parity
    RADIO_UBRG = ((Fcyc/38400)/16)-1; //9600 baud //38400 //((Fcyc/38400)/16)-1
    //COMM_UBRG = 259;          // 9600 baud @ 80MHz
    RADIO_USTAbits.UTXISEL0 = 0;        // Interrupt when there is room in TX FIFO
    RADIO_USTAbits.URXISEL = 0;     // Interrupt when a character is received

    // Configure DMA channel 1 as Comm Uart transmit
    DMA1CONbits.DIR = 1;    // DMA reads from SRAM, writes to peripheral
    DMA1CONbits.AMODE = 00; // Addr. mode is register indirect w/ post increment
    DMA1CONbits.MODE = 0b01;// One-shot, no ping-pong mode.
    DMA1CONbits.SIZE = 1;   // Transfer 1 byte at a time
    DMA1REQbits.IRQSEL = 0b0001100;     // DMA1 writes to UART1 TX (the Comm uart port.)
    DMA1PAD = (volatile unsigned int) &RADIO_UTXREG; //Tell DMA module address of COMM TX register
    DMA1STA = __builtin_dmaoffset(txBuff);  // Tell DMA module start address of our dma tx buffer
    IFS0bits.DMA1IF = 0;    // Clear DMA interrupt flag
    //IEC0bits.DMA1IE = 1;    // Enable DMA interrupt

    //Configure DMA channel 0 as Comm Uart receive
    DMA0CONbits.MODE = 0b00; // Continuous no Ping-Pong mode
    DMA0CNT = RADIO_RX_BUFFER_SIZE - 1;
    DMA0REQbits.IRQSEL = 0b0001011;     // DMA0 reads from UART1 RX (the Comm uart port.)
    DMA0PAD = (volatile unsigned int) &RADIO_URXREG;
    DMA0STA = __builtin_dmaoffset(rxBuff); // Tell DMA start addr. of buffer A
    //DMA0STB = __builtin_dmaoffset(rxBuffB); // Tell DMA start addr. of buffer B
    IFS0bits.DMA0IF = 0;    // Clear DMA interrupt flag
    //IEC0bits.DMA0IE = 1;    // Enable DMA interrupt

    DMA0CONbits.CHEN = 1;   // Enable RX DMA channel only. TX channel is one-shot mode.

    // UART config for CLI
    BEACON_UMODEbits.STSEL = 0; //1-stop bit
    BEACON_UMODEbits.PDSEL = 0; //No Parity, 8-data bits
    BEACON_UMODEbits.ABAUD = 0; // Autobaud Disabled
    BEACON_UBRG = ((Fcyc/9600)/16)-1; // 9600 baud @ 80Mhz
    BEACON_USTAbits.UTXISEL0 = 0; // interrupt after 1 Tx char is transmited
    //BEACON_USTAbits.UTXISEL1 = 0;
    BEACON_USTAbits.URXISEL = 0; // interrrupt after 1 Rx char is received
    BEACON_UMODEbits.UARTEN = 1; // Enable UART
    BEACON_USTAbits.UTXEN = 1; // Enable Uart Tx
    IEC4bits.U2EIE = 0; // Enable error interrupt

    //Tx config for CLI
    DMA4REQ = 0x001F; // Uart2 transmiter
    DMA4PAD = (volatile unsigned int) &BEACON_UTXREG;// Tell DMA module address of COMM TX register
    DMA4CONbits.AMODE = 0; // Addr. mode is register indirect x/ post increment
    DMA4CONbits.MODE = 1; // One-Shot
    DMA4CONbits.DIR = 1; // reads from RAM writes to peripheral
    DMA4CONbits.SIZE = 1;// Transfers 1 byte at a time
    // count needs to be pushed into interrupt and counted there, will avoid weird shit
    DMA4CNT = 7; // 11 DMA requests
    DMA4STA = __builtin_dmaoffset(tx0Buff); // Tell DMA module start address of our dma tx buffer
    IFS2bits.DMA4IF = 0; // Clear DMA interrupt flag
    IEC2bits.DMA4IE = 1; // Enable DMA interrupt

    // Rx config for CLI
    DMA3REQ = 0x001E; // Uart2 Receive
    DMA3PAD = (volatile unsigned int) &BEACON_URXREG; // Tell DMA module address of COMM RX register
    DMA3CONbits.AMODE = 0; // Addr. mode is register indirect x/ post increment
    DMA3CONbits.MODE = 2; // Ping-Pong
    DMA3CONbits.DIR = 0; // reads from peripheral writes to RAM
    DMA3CONbits.SIZE = 0; // Transfers 1 word at a time
    DMA3CNT = 7; // 11 DMA requests
    DMA3STA = __builtin_dmaoffset(tx0Buff); // Tell DMA start addr. of receive buffer
    DMA3STB = __builtin_dmaoffset(rx0Buff); // Tell DMA start addr. of receive buffer
    DMA3CONbits.CHEN = 1; // Enable RX DMA channel only. TX channel is one-shot mode.
    IFS2bits.DMA3IF = 0; // Clear DMA interrupt
    IEC2bits.DMA3IE = 1; // Enable DMA interrupt
    // END of added code

    // these bits must be at end of file
    RADIO_UMODEbits.UARTEN = 1;     //enable uart
    RADIO_USTAbits.UTXEN = 1;       //transmit enabled

}

/**
 * Writes a string to the comm Port. The length must be less than COMM_TX_BUFFER_SIZE
 * or this function will have no effect.
 * @param str The string to write.
 * @param len The number of bytes to write
 * @pre uart_commInit() must be called before calling this function.
 * @note This function call is blocking. It waits until the last transfer is
 * finished to begin current transmission. Once current transmission has been
 * started then it will return because the DMA module handles transmission of data.
 */

void BEACON_uart_commPuts(char *str, uint16 len){
    #if DEBUG_OUTPUT
    uint16 *targetAddr;
    if(len == 0 || len > BEACON_TX_BUFFER_SIZE)
    return;     //TODO Handle error
    while(!BEACON_commIsTXReady());   // Blocking!
    targetAddr = (uint16 *) (DMA4STA + ((unsigned int) &_DMA_BASE));    // Address of DMA buffer
    memcpy((void *) targetAddr, (const void *) str, len);   // Copy data into DMA buffer
    DMA4CNT = len-1;        // Send len # of characters
    DMA4CONbits.CHEN = 1;   // Turn on the DMA channel
    DMA4REQbits.FORCE = 1;  // Start DMA transfer to comm UART
    #endif

}


/**
 * Retrieves a string from the Comm. Port. The caller must ensure that the 'str'
 * parameter can handle the number of bytes being requested in parameter 'len'.
 * @param str The string to store the received characters in.
 * @param len The maximum number of characters to return. The number of chars
 *      copied to str will be less than or equal to len.
 * @return int16 The number of bytes copied to str if non-negative or an error
 *      code if negative.
 * @pre uart_commInit() must be called before calling this function.
 * @todo Add overrun detection
 * @todo Implement error codes if necessary.
 */
int16 RADIO_uart_commGets(char *str, uint16 len){
/* The DMA transfers 2 bytes of data into the DMA buffer for every byte it
 * receives from the UART (see dsPIC33 reference manual DMA chapter). The
 * lower byte is the data received by the UART and the upper byte has 2
 * status bits. There is one DMA receive buffer (no Ping-Pong mode) which the
 * DMA starts to fill 2 bytes at a time until the buffer is full then goes
 * back to the beginning and starts to put new characters in the beginning
 * of the buffer again. This code reads up to 'len' bytes (not transfers!) from the buffer
 * starting from the last location readmup to the last byte available in
 * the DMA buffer. If the DMA rolled over to the beginning since the last read,
 * this function reads until the end of the buffer, then from the beginning.
 * This should be called often enough to prevent overruns.
 *
 * NOTE: For every 2 bytes this function reads from the DMA buffer it only
 * returns one because the upper byte of each transfer are status bits.
 */
    uint16 numTransfers, i; // # of DMA transfers (not bytes!) to return to caller.
    uint16 *lastArrived = (uint16 *)(DMA0STA + ((unsigned int) &_DMA_BASE));  // Points after most recent transfer received in DMA buffer
    //static uint16 *lastRead = (uint16 *) &rxBuff; // Points to next transfer to be read
    if(lastArrived < lastRead){     // Rollover occured
        // (1) # of transfers till end of buffer.
        // (2) # of transfers in the beginning of buffer.
        numTransfers = (uint16) ((rxBuff + RADIO_RX_BUFFER_SIZE - 1) - lastRead);
        numTransfers += (uint16) (lastArrived - rxBuff);
    }else{
        numTransfers = (uint16) (lastArrived - lastRead);
    }

    if(len < numTransfers)  // Don't give caller more bytes than they can handle
        numTransfers = len;

    for(i = 0; i < numTransfers; i++){  // Now copy chars into caller's buffer
        /*if(i == 0){
            uart_commGetc();
            continue;
        }*/
        if(lastRead >= rxBuff + RADIO_RX_BUFFER_SIZE){  // Handle rollover
            lastRead = rxBuff;     // Start reading from beginning now
        }
        // Mask off status byte and only copy the lower char to callers buffer
        *str = (char) (*lastRead & 0xFF);
        str++;      // Increment index into caller's buffer
        lastRead++; // Increment read index
    }
    return i;   // # of bytes returned in parameter 1.
}

int16 BEACON_uart_commGets(char *str, uint16 len){
    /* The DMA transfers 2 bytes of data into the DMA buffer for every byte it
     * receives from the UART (see dsPIC33 reference manual DMA chapter). The
     * lower byte is the data received by the UART and the upper byte has 2
     * status bits. There is one DMA receive buffer (no Ping-Pong mode) which the
     * DMA starts to fill 2 bytes at a time until the buffer is full then goes
     * back to the beginning and starts to put new characters in the beginning
     * of the buffer again. This code reads up to 'len' bytes (not transfers!) from the buffer
     * starting from the last location readmup to the last byte available in
     * the DMA buffer. If the DMA rolled over to the beginning since the last read,
     * this function reads until the end of the buffer, then from the beginning.
     * This should be called often enough to prevent overruns.
     *
     * NOTE: For every 2 bytes this function reads from the DMA buffer it only
     * returns one because the upper byte of each transfer are status bits.
     */
    uint16 numTransfers, i; // # of DMA transfers (not bytes!) to return to caller.
    uint16 *lastArrived = (uint16 *)(DMA3STA + ((unsigned int) &_DMA_BASE));  // Points after most recent transfer received in DMA buffer
    //static uint16 *lastRead = (uint16 *) &rxBuff; // Points to next transfer to be read
    if(lastArrived < lastRead){     // Rollover occured
        // (1) # of transfers till end of buffer.
        // (2) # of transfers in the beginning of buffer.
        numTransfers = (uint16) ((rx0Buff + BEACON_RX_BUFFER_SIZE - 1) - lastRead);
        numTransfers += (uint16) (lastArrived - rx0Buff);
    }else{
        numTransfers = (uint16) (lastArrived - lastRead);
    }

    if(len < numTransfers)  // Don't give caller more bytes than they can handle
        numTransfers = len;

    for(i = 0; i < numTransfers; i++){  // Now copy chars into caller's buffer
        /*if(i == 0){
         uart_commGetc();
         continue;
         }*/
        if(lastRead >= rx0Buff + BEACON_RX_BUFFER_SIZE){  // Handle rollover
            lastRead = rx0Buff;     // Start reading from beginning now
        }
        // Mask off status byte and only copy the lower char to callers buffer
        *str = (char) (*lastRead & 0xFF);
        str++;      // Increment index into caller's buffer
        lastRead++; // Increment read index
    }
    return i;   // # of bytes returned in parameter 1.
}

/**
 * Retrieves a single character from the comm receive buffer.
 * @return (int16) returns a signed integer. If the value is less than zero there
 * were no characters in the UART receive buffer to return. Otherwise, the return
 * value should be cast to a char and used accordingly.
 * @pre uart_commInit() must be called before calling this function.
 */
int16 RADIO_uart_commGetc(){
    int16 retValue;
    if(RADIO_uart_commNumRXBytes() > 0){
        if(lastRead >= rxBuff + RADIO_RX_BUFFER_SIZE){  // Handle rollover
            lastRead = rxBuff;     // Start reading from beginning now
        }
        retValue = (int16) *lastRead;
        lastRead++;
        return retValue;
    }
    return -1;
}

/**
 * Retrieves a single character from the comm receive buffer.
 * @return (int16) returns a signed integer. If the value is less than zero there
 * were no characters in the UART receive buffer to return. Otherwise, the return
 * value should be cast to a char and used accordingly.
 * @pre uart_commInit() must be called before calling this function.
 */
int16 BEACON_uart_commGetc(){
    int16 retValue;
    if(BEACON_uart_commNumRXBytes() > 0){
        if(lastRead >= rx0Buff + BEACON_RX_BUFFER_SIZE){  // Handle rollover
            lastRead = rx0Buff;     // Start reading from beginning now
        }
        retValue = (int16) *lastRead;
        lastRead++;
        return retValue;
    }
    return -1;
}

/**
 * Looks for and retrieves a string from the comm port up to and including the
 * specified terminating character. If the terminating character does not exist
 * in the uart buffer no characters are copied to str and -1 is returned.
 * @param str A buffer to stored the received data in
 * @param len Maximum number of characters to retrieve
 * @param terminator the terminating character
 * @return The number of characters copied to str, -1 if no terminator not found or buffer to small for command
 */
int16 uart_commGetToChar(char *str, uint16 len, char terminator){
   BOOL foundChar = FALSE;
   int16 i, strLen = 0;       // strLen is the value we will return
   uint16 *tempPtr = lastRead;  // Points after the last read DMA transfer (transfer = 2 bytes)
   uint16 *lastArrived = (uint16 *)(DMA0STA + ((unsigned int) &_DMA_BASE));  // Points after most recent transfer received in DMA buffer
   len = (len < (i = RADIO_uart_commNumRXBytes())) ? len : i;    // If numCharsReceived > len then len = numCharsReceived

   // Look for null terminating character
   while(!foundChar){   // Loop until char is found or 'till end of received chars
      if(strLen >= len){
     return -1;  // Provided buffer not long enough or terminating char not found.
      }

      if((char) (*tempPtr & 0xFF) == terminator){  // Found terminating char?
     foundChar = TRUE;
     strLen++;   // To count terminating character
      }else{
     strLen++;   // Increment # of transfers we're planning to copy to user's buffer
     tempPtr++;  // Increment pointer to the receive buffer
     if(tempPtr >= rxBuff + RADIO_RX_BUFFER_SIZE){  // Handle rollover in rxBuff
           tempPtr = rxBuff;                // Start reading from beginning now
     }
      }
   }

   for(i = 0; i < strLen; i++){  // Now copy chars into caller's buffer
     if(lastRead >= rxBuff + RADIO_RX_BUFFER_SIZE){  // Handle rollover in rxBuff
     lastRead = rxBuff;     // Start reading from beginning now
     }
     // Mask off status byte and only copy the lower char to caller's buffer
     *str = (char) (*lastRead & 0xFF);
     str++;     // Increment index into caller's buffer
     lastRead++;    // Increment read index
   }
   return strLen;   // # of bytes INCLUDING terminating character
}

/**
 * Returns the number of unread characters in the comm UART buffer.
 * @return (int16) number of unread chars in comm UART buffer
 * @pre uart_commInit() must be called before calling this function.
 */
int16 RADIO_uart_commNumRXBytes(){
    int16 retValue;
    uint16 *lastReceivedChar = (uint16 *)(DMA0STA + ((unsigned int) &_DMA_BASE));
    if(lastReceivedChar >= lastRead){
        return (int16) (lastReceivedChar - lastRead);
    }else{
        retValue = (int16) ((uint16 *)(&rxBuff + RADIO_TX_BUFFER_SIZE) - lastRead);
        retValue += (uint16) (lastReceivedChar - (uint16 *)&rxBuff);
        return retValue;
    }
}

int16 BEACON_uart_commNumRXBytes(){
    int16 retValue;
    uint16 *lastReceivedChar = (uint16 *)(DMA2STA + ((unsigned int) &_DMA_BASE));
    if(lastReceivedChar >= lastRead){
        return (int16) (lastReceivedChar - lastRead);
    }else{
        retValue = (int16) ((uint16 *)(&rx0Buff + BEACON_TX_BUFFER_SIZE) - lastRead);
        retValue += (uint16) (lastReceivedChar - (uint16 *)&rx0Buff);
        return retValue;
    }
}

/* Interrupt Handlers */

//void __attribute__((__interrupt__,no_auto_psv)) _U2EInterrupt(void){
//    TODO Handle Uart Error
//}

/**
 * Comm receive DMA interrupt service routine. Currently not used.
 */
void __attribute__((__interrupt__,no_auto_psv)) _DMA0Interrupt(void){
    IFS0bits.DMA0IF = 0;    // Clear DMA interrupt flag
}

/**
 * Comm transmit DMA interrupt service routine. Currently not used.
 */
void __attribute__((__interrupt__,no_auto_psv)) _DMA1Interrupt(void){
    IFS0bits.DMA1IF = 0;    // Clear DMA interrupt flag
}

/**
 * Comm receive DMA interrupt service routine. 
 */
void __attribute__((__interrupt__,no_auto_psv)) _DMA3Interrupt(void){

    static unsigned int BufferCount = 0;

    if(BufferCount == 0){
        DMA4STA = __builtin_dmaoffset(tx0Buff);
    }
    else{
        DMA4STA = __builtin_dmaoffset(rx0Buff);
    }

    DMA4CONbits.CHEN = 1; // Re-enable DMA3 channel
    DMA4REQbits.FORCE = 1; // manual start the transfers, if we doing predetermined transfer size

    BufferCount ^= 1;

    IFS2bits.DMA3IF = 0; // Clear DMA3 Interrupt flag
}

/**
 * Comm transmit DMA interrupt service routine. Currently not used.
 */
void __attribute__((__interrupt__,no_auto_psv)) _DMA4Interrupt(void){
    IFS2bits.DMA4IF = 0;    // Clear DMA interrupt flag
}

/**
 * @}
 */
```

uart.h

```
/**
 * This header file provides function prototypes and macros for UART ports.
 *
 * @ingroup CSuart
 */

/**
 * @ingroup CSuart
 * @{ 
 */
#ifndef CSUART_H
#define CSUART_H

/* Include Files */
#include <p33Fxxxx.h>

/**
 * Register definitions for Comm port uart
 * Change these values to use the other uart port.
 * WARNING: Must also change values in uart_commInit(). (DMA1REQbits.IRQSEL)
 * @cond
 */
/*NOTE:(8/20/14, 3:53pm) these macros have been changed, U2 -> U1 */
#define RADIO_UMODE U1MODE
#define RADIO_UMODEbits U1MODEbits
#define RADIO_USTA  U1STA
#define RADIO_USTAbits  U1STAbits
#define RADIO_URXREG    U1RXREG
#define RADIO_UTXREG    U1TXREG
#define RADIO_UBRG  U1BRG
#define RADIO_URXIF      IFS0bits.U1RXIF     // Comm uart receive interrupt flag
#define RADIO_UTXIF      IFS0bits.U1TXIF     // Comm uart transmite interrupt flag
#define RADIO_RXIntEnable()    {IEC0bits.U1RXIE = 1;}
#define RADIO_TXIntEnable()    {IEC0bits.U1TXIE = 1;}
#define RADIO_ErrorIntEnable() {IEC4bits.U1EIE = 1;}
#define RADIO_RXIntDisable()    {IEC0bits.U1RXIE = 0;}
#define RADIO_TXIntDisable()    {IEC0bits.U1TXIE = 0;}
#define RADIO_ErrorIntDisable() {IEC4bits.U1EIE = 0;}

#define BEACON_UMODEbits    U2MODEbits
#define BEACON_USTAbits         U2STAbits
#define BEACON_URXREG           U2RXREG
#define BEACON_UTXREG       U2TXREG
#define BEACON_UBRG         U2BRG
#define BEACON_IFSbits          IFS2bits


#define RADIO_TX_BUFFER_SIZE        283  /// Size of comm port's DMA transmit buffer in bytes
#define RADIO_RX_BUFFER_SIZE        128  /// Size of comm port's DMA receive buffer in bytes

#define BEACON_TX_BUFFER_SIZE       128  /// Size of comm port's DMA transmit buffer in bytes
#define BEACON_RX_BUFFER_SIZE       128  /// Size of comm port's DMA receive buffer in bytes


/**
 * Returns 1 when the comm port UART is ready to transmit, and 0 otherwise.
 */
#define RADIO_commIsTXReady()     (RADIO_USTAbits.TRMT)

#define BEACON_commIsTXReady()     (BEACON_USTAbits.TRMT)

/* Function Prototypes */
void uart_commInit();
void BEACON_uart_commPuts(char *str, uint16 len);
void uart0_commPuts(char *str, uint16 len);
int16 RADIO_uart_commGets(char *str, uint16 len);
//int16 uart0_commGets(char *str, uint16 len);
int16 RADIO_uart_commGetc();
//int16 uart0_commGetc();
int16 uart_commGetToChar(char *str, uint16 len, char terminator);
//int16 uart0_commGetToChar(char *str, uint16 len, char terminator);
int16 RADIO_uart_commNumRXBytes();
//int16 uart0_commNumRXBytes();


/**
 * @}
 */

#endif  /* CSUART_H */
```

Comment: TLDR; you need to learn how to whittle down your code to the bare minimum that exhibits the problem. That will make the lives of those helping you easier and, in fact, it may even make the problem blindingly obvious to you, to the point where you don't even _need_ to ask a question :-)

Comment: thanks that didnt help at all

Comment: deathlok, I'm trying to educate you on how best to ask questions here in order to be more likely to get a response. Few people are going to wade through 500+ lines of code looking for your problem, expecially when there's a better way. You can choose to ignore me if you wish, but I'd be more inclined to take the advice from someone who's been here a while rather than just ignore it. Best of luck.

Comment: thanks guy, the problem was with the buffer, you needed the whole code to see it. according to the spec, the interrupt fires when the buffer is full. also i mentioned which ares the problem was, included entire code a courtesy.

Comment: Hi,
What was the exact problem in your code, which was causing no DMA interrupt on recieve. The UART part in the docs says that when DMA is used for Rx, the DMA size should be set to 16 bits or WORD transfer. But the example code does not do so. It keeps the DMAXCONbits.SIZE to 0 which is a BYTE. Your response will help me get going on this issue. Thanks in advance.